# For what values of $k$ to both of the following series converge?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, power-series

I'm taking the AP Calculus BC Exam next week and ran into this problem with no idea how to solve it. Unfortunately, the answer key didn't provide explanations, and I'd really, really appreciate it if someone could explain how to solve this problem, and why the answer is 4. It's a non-calculator question.

For which of the following values of k do both

$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac3k\right)^n\;\;\;\text{ and}\;\;\;\;\; \sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(3-k)^n}{\sqrt{n+3}}$$ converge?

Answer choices: None, 2, 3, 4, 5.

Comment: If $k=3$ then the left hand sum is $\sum 1$ which diverges.

Answer (score 1):

Since an infinite geometric series converges iff $\;|r|<1\;$ , with $\;r=$ the series fixed ratio, the first given series already tells you that the first three options are false.

For the second series you can use the $\;n-$th root test for the absolute value:

$$\sqrt[n]{\left|\frac{(3-k)^n}{\sqrt{n+3}}\right|}=\frac{|3-k|}{\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n-3}}}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}|3-k|$$

Try now to take it from here

Comment: So abs(3 - k) has to be < 1; doesn't abs(3-4) = 1 and not <1 though?

Comment: @Ozymandias Yes, it must be $$\;|3-k|<1\iff -1<3-k<1\iff-4<-k<-2\iff 2<k<4$$ You may also want to check *the extreme points* of this interval. This already will give you the exact option for the answer.

Comment: At k=4, it converges because the limit becomes 1 over the root n thing (with n going to infinity), which is 0. Is this the right thought process?

Comment: @Ozymandias At $\;k=4\;$ the series converges because iyou get a Leibniz series when you substitute $\;k=4\;$ in the expression, *not* because the limit is zero, **which is not** . Remember, $\;\sqrt[n]x\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}1\;$ for *any* $\;x>0\;$ , and thus also $\;\sqrt[n]{\sqrt{n-3}}\to 1\;$

Answer (score 0):

For $$a_n={(\frac{3}{k})}^n$$, we know if $k \le 3 $, it can not pass the divergent test, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$. So the answer is between 4 and 5.

For $$a_n=\frac{(3−k)^n}{n+3}$$, when $k=5$ it is  $$a_n=(-1)^n\frac{2^n}{n+3}$$. it cannot pass alternating series test, i.e. $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n =0$. But it can pass the test with k=4. So the answer 4 is right.